# Bokeh Plot: Overlay a plot and a Div to get a gradient background using Bokeh

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, bokehjs

### Initial Goal

I have a candlestick plot in Bokeh that is essentially a clone of [the MSFT candlesticks example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/candlestick.html) but with my custom data.

All I want is a grey-black gradient background behind that plot.

### What I've Tried

Bokeh doesn't have `background_gradient_fill` option, so I tried using an [`image_url`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting/figure.html#bokeh.plotting.Figure.image_url) I found online of a gradient, that didn't work because firefox doesn't allow third party image loading. This option sucks anyway because it's slow and relies on some url off google.

I tried making my own gradient numpy array and them adding that as [an `image`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/image.html) that didn't work because the image coords are basically hard-coded onto my plot, but my candlesticks are dynamic and are being loaded in live.

I finally thought I'd make a Gradient [`Div`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/_modules/bokeh/models/widgets/markups.html#Div) [styled using CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/4L8drug1/9/), set the candlestick plot fill to transparent, then overlay on top of each other. I tried doing that using `gridplot`, `column`, `row` and neither really allows you to control the offset of the elements within it from what I've seen. So now I don't really know what to do...

How do I squash the two together?

### What I Have Now:

My code currently produces this:
[image]

I just want both of these on top of each other basically. How do I do so?

---

#### Minimal Repliclable Example:

The MRE for this is the same as [the MSFT candlesticks example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/candlestick.html) but with the added div. To run, just place this code in a python file and run `bokeh sampledata` to download sample data then `bokeh serve --show yourfilename.py`

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import Div
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import MSFT
from math import pi

df = pd.DataFrame(MSFT)[:50]
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

inc = df.close > df.open
dec = df.open > df.close
w = 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000  # half day in ms

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools=TOOLS, width=1000, title="MSFT Candlestick")
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi / 4
p.grid.grid_line_alpha = 0.3

div = Div(style={"background": "linear-gradient(rgb(40,40,40), rgb(10,10,10))",
                 "height": "1000px", "width": "1000px"}, sizing_mode="scale_both")

p.segment(df.date, df.high, df.date, df.low, color="black")
p.vbar(df.date[inc], w, df.open[inc], df.close[inc], fill_color="#D5E1DD", line_color="black")
p.vbar(df.date[dec], w, df.open[dec], df.close[dec], fill_color="#F2583E", line_color="black")

curdoc().add_root(gridplot([[p, div]], toolbar_location="left"))
```

Comment: Bokeh does not support overlays of this sort.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a gradient background, you can build it manually. You can generate an image based on the values of X and Y axis and than map these values to a Linear Colour Map.

```py
from math import pi
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import LinearColorMapper
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import MSFT

df = pd.DataFrame(MSFT)[:50]
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

min_price = min(df.close.min(), df.open.min())
max_price = max(df.close.max(), df.open.max())

inc = df.close > df.open
dec = df.open > df.close
w = 12*60*60*1000 # half day in ms

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools=TOOLS, width=1000, title = "MSFT Candlestick", 
           x_range=[df.date.min(), df.date.max()], y_range=[min_price-10, max_price+10])
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
p.grid.grid_line_alpha=0.3

# Gradient background
x = np.linspace(1, 0, 256)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 256)

xArray, yArray = np.meshgrid(x, y)
plotArray = np.sqrt(xArray + yArray)

color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette="Greys256", low=0, high=1)

p.image(image=[plotArray], color_mapper=color_mapper, dw_units='screen', dw=1000, dh=max_price-min_price+20, x=[df.date.min()], 
        y=[min_price-10])

p.segment(df.date, df.high, df.date, df.low, color="black")
p.vbar(df.date[inc], w, df.open[inc], df.close[inc], fill_color="#D5E1DD", line_color="black")
p.vbar(df.date[dec], w, df.open[dec], df.close[dec], fill_color="#F2583E", line_color="black")

show(p)
```

The code above gives the following result:
[image: bokeh plot with gradient background]